# Polymer, use multiline attribute on paper-input in ajax-form

Tags: polymer

I tried to make a multi-line paper-input in ajax-form element

```css
#info {
   width: 90%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 20px auto;
 }

paper-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
   <form is="ajax-form"  action="../../../back/saveIMG.php" class="picturePost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <file-input camera name="pic" id="pic">
       <core-icon-button
                         icon="image:camera-alt">
       </core-icon-button>
     </file-input>
     <br/>
     <paper-input multiline id="last" floatingLabel label="Commentaire" ></paper-input>
     <!-- -->
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" name="submitInfo">
   </form>
</div>
```

So I added some attribute like `maxRows="5"` and `rows="3"` but no way my paper-input are always a single line area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `paper-input` you should consider using [paper-input-decorator](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-input-decorator.html) with [paper-autogrow-textarea](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/paper-autogrow-textarea.html)

```
<div id="info">
    <form is="ajax-form"  action="../../../back/saveIMG.php" class="picturePost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <file-input camera name="pic" id="pic">
            <core-icon-button icon="image:camera-alt"></core-icon-button>
        </file-input>
        <br/>
        <paper-input-decorator id="last" label="Commentaire">
            <paper-autogrow-textarea rows="3" maxRows="5">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </paper-autogrow-textarea>
        </paper-input-decorator>
        <!-- -->
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitInfo">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This elements will be deprecated so i search to resolve this attribut bug.

Comment: Where did you get that information? Browsing through the Polymer 0.8 alpha repository, I noticed that paper-input-decorator is [imported into the initial 0.8 repository](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/tree/0.8-initial-port). I doubt that they will remove such a useful feature

Comment: Furthermore, browsing through the [current docs](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html) I find that the multiline attribute isn't supported. Maybe it was in an older version of Polymer, but it surely isn't in 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `paper-input` try to use `iron-autogrow-textarea`:

```
<iron-autogrow-textarea id="last" rows="3" maxRows="5" bind-value="{{xyz}}">
</iron-autogrow-textarea>
```

Documentation: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-autogrow-textarea